# New to Git Hub I have code on my local system and I want to get the latest code there committed by other team member how I could do that

Tags: github

I need a command to update the latest code from the Master repository. Like SVN, we do an update and it will give you latest code.

I am trying to use

```
sudo git pull origin master
```

but it says already up to date. I have tried to do

```
git reset --hard HEAD
sudo git pull origin master
```

as well but it is also not working.

Comment: where is the location of you master repository ? github or another host ?

Comment: Did your teammates push their commits?

Comment: You should not need to use `sudo` to run the `git` command. Unless by some strange reason you cloned the repository as root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if you are on the right branch (master):

git branch

It should look like this:

* master

If it isn't, type:

git checkout master

Comment: You also want to ensure the other team member has successfully `push`ed their changes to GitHub and that those changes were on the `master` branch and not a topic branch.